# How to Create a Pivot Table in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to create a Pivot table, but getting `Invalid Procedure Call or Argument`.

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="rng", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="rngB", TableName:="pvtReportA_B", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

- `rng` (The source) is a range consisting of about 20 columns and a few thousand rows.
- `rngB` (The destination) is a single cell in a different worksheet

Can anyone advise where I am going wrong?

EDIT:

My fault, I should have been using `rngData` and not `rng` as the Source.

```
    Set rng = wsA.Range("C14")
    Set rngData = Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight))
    Set rngData = Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
    Set rngB = wsB.Range("C8")

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngData, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=rngB, TableName:="pvtReportA_B", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

This brings up the PivotTable frame just fine.

Comment: You can set the data range with one line of code:
    `Set rngData = range(wsA.Range("C14"),wsA.Range("C14").end(xlToRight).end(xlDown))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this instance, I used the wrong range object, which caused Excel to throw a fit.

```
Set rng = wsA.Range("C14")
Set rngData = Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight))
Set rngData = Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
Set rngB = wsB.Range("C8")

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngData, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=rngB, TableName:="pvtReportA_B", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

Comment: In third line of code you should put 'rngData' instead of 'rng'

Answer (score 4):

To create a pivot in **Excel 2010**, using VBA code, you can use and adapt this template:

```
Sub newPVT()
    Dim PTCache As PivotCache
    Dim PT As PivotTable

    'Create the Cache
    Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=Range("Dynamic_Field_Summary"))

    'Select the destination sheet
    Sheets("Field Summary").Select

    'Create the Pivot table
    Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, _
        TableDestination:=Range("P1"), TableName:="Pivot1")

    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True

    'Adding fields
    With PT
        With .PivotFields("Enterprise")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        With .PivotFields("Field")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        With .PivotFields("Planted Acres")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Position = 1
            .Caption = " Planted Acres"
            .Function = xlSum
        End With

        With .PivotFields("Harvested Acres")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Position = 2
            .Caption = " Harvested Acres"
            .Function = xlSum
        End With

        With .PivotFields("lbs")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Position = 3
            .Caption = " lbs"
            .Function = xlSum
        End With

        'Adjusting some settings
        .RowGrand = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = False
        .HasAutoFormat = False

        'Improving the layout
        .TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"
        .ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
        .ShowTableStyleColumnStripes = True

    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        'Adjusting columns width
        .Columns("P:V").ColumnWidth = 16
        .Range("Q2:V2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
End Sub
```

I found it [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/711451-tabledestination-pivot-table-macro.html).

In [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243933%28v=office.14%29.aspx) you can also fine the meaning of every part of the code, for example is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlpivotfieldorientation%28v=office.11%29.aspx).
I think that this is a good code also to start creating vba macros for Excel 2007 or other versions.