# Dynamically creating a pivot table using fuzzy matching

Tags: vba, excel

So, I'm constantly being given data in new and different formats. I'm on a crusade to get my work to standardize data for easy use, and if I managed to convince the powers that be to standardize data, this problem becomes entirely moot. Until then, I have the following problem:

I get data in a variety of ways. Sometimes my gross sales are called total sales. Sometimes gross sales before discounts, total sales before discounts, Gross_Sales, etc. Discounts, deductions, exempt amounts, etc. form another column. So on and so forth. I'd like to be able to do the following:

1) Figure out what columns I want,
2) Turn those columns into a pivot table.

For part 1, I have two options, and I'm wondering if there's anymore: The 1st is to use Microsoft's fuzzy-matching add-in to help me match. I'd have a separate tab dedicated to fuzzy matching each column I need. The second is to just generate a long list of all the variants, and to test each one until I find a hit, assign it, and move onto testing the next one.

The second part is turning all of this into a pivot table - the resouces I have so far are https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables and [How to Create a Pivot Table in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861909/how-to-create-a-pivot-table-in-vba)

Is there a better method? Is there another way?

Edit: Slightly better method - Grab the data columns, place them into a table, and pivot everything off of that table - it removes the need to re-create pivot tables, just need to move the data over.

Answer (score 2):

Having the same problem, I use a mix of your two methods.

My data consists of a bunch of logs for rejected x-ray images, and the reject reason is a free text field. My solution was to create a table where the first column contains my desired output categories, and then each subsequent column contains a different variation of it.

For example, a row might have (column one/ouput first entry):

> Positioning, POS, Positioning Error, Patient Positioning

Note that these are all fairly different from each other. Where the fuzzy matching comes in - it is used to capture all the smaller differences and mispellings *around* those other columns. When the fuzzy matching section decides a given reason matches a column's entry, it is then replaced with the appropriate desired output reason from column 1 of the table. In my example, a reason of 'Possitioning Err' [sic] would match to column 3 (Positioning Error) and then get converted to Positioning.

Then wash rinse repeat over the rest of your data as needed. This approach  was super useful and fairly flexible in helping standardize my data. It was also computationally more expensive, but you'd only need to run the matching portion once I guess.

As for the actual mechanics of going about doing this - I use 2010, so no inbuilt functionality. I run the fuzzy matching code on a temporary worksheet until best percentage matches are found, and then overwrite the actual source data afterwards.

Comment: Hey, I had a similar thing with free text issues - I'd look into regular expressions, they're amazing with free text. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: Thanks, they might be more computationally simpler. I'm still worried that someone, somehow, will find a new and exciting way to mispell things so badly that regex can't pick it up :\